# Heap array allocates 4 extra bytes if class has destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, destructor, allocation

I'm new to C++ and I've been playing around with memory allocation lately. I have found out that when  you declare a class with a destructor, like so:

```
class B
{
public:
    ~B() { }
};
```

And then create a heap array of it like so:

```
B* arr = new B[8];
```

The allocator allocates 12 bytes but when I remove the destructor, it only allocates 8 bytes. This is how I'm measuring the allocation:

```
size_t allocated = 0;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    allocated += size;
    return malloc(size);
}
void deallocate(B* array, size_t size)
{
    delete[] array;
    allocated -= size * sizeof(B);
}
```

Of course I have to call `deallocate` manually while the `new` operator is called automatically.

I have found this problem while working with an `std::string*` and I realised that the deallocator worked fine with an `int*` but not with the former.

Does anyone know why that happens and more importantly: **How to detect these programmatically at runtime?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How to detect these programatically at runtime?" - why do you want to?

Comment: @Dai I'm just playing around seeing how C++ works. Why shouldn't be using `malloc` like that?

Comment: My comment wasn't about using `malloc` particularly - but if you're doing this as a mental exercise that's fine; I was just concerned you might be doing this in production code. I deleted it.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813448/does-operator-newsize-t-use-malloc

Comment: @Dai Thanks I'll check that out.

Comment: "I'd like to know what's wrong with malloc" -- `malloc` is fine to use in a `new` implementation, but it needs to be consistent. You _cannot_ `delete[]` memory allocated with `malloc` -- they're different functions, and it's formally undefined behavior. See [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184537/1678770) and [Behaviour of malloc with delete in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10854210/1678770)

Comment: It's a guess, so I dont want to post an answer, but - adding a non-default destructor makes the class non-trivially destructible. Releasing an array of trivially-destructible objects only requires calling `free()`, but for non-trivially destructible you also have to call destructors. The extra 8 bytes would then be bookkeeping data for compiler, it probably stores number of elements there, so that it can run correct number of destructors before releasing the memory.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Thanks for the sources. I'll definetly check them out. But say I change the implementation of the `new` operator, it still doesn't account for the difference between the `size` in its parameter being 12 bytes when the type has a destructor and 8 bytes when it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at an implementation detail of how your compiler treats `new[]` and `delete[]`, so there isn't a definitive answer for the extra space being allocated since the answer will be specific to an implementation -- though I can provide a likely reason below.

Since this is implementation-defined, you **cannot** reliably detect this at runtime. More importantly, there **shouldn't be any real reason to do this**. Especially if you're new to C++, this fact is more of an interesting/esoteric thing to know of, but there should be no real benefit detecting this at runtime.

It's important to also be aware that this only happens with array-allocations, and not with object allocations. For example, the following will print expected numbers:

```cpp
struct A {
    ~A(){}
};
struct B {
};

auto operator new(std::size_t n) -> void* {
    std::cout << "Allocated: " << n << std::endl;
    return std::malloc(n);
}
auto operator delete(void* p, std::size_t n) -> void {
    std::free(p);
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto* a = new A{};
    delete a;

    auto* b = new B{};
    delete b;
}
```

Output:

```
Allocated: 1
Allocated: 1
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/53PqYfT4a)</kbd>

The extra storage only gets allocated for types with non-trivial destructors:

```cpp
    auto* a = new A[10];
    delete[] a;

    auto* b = new B[10];
    delete[] b;
```

Outputs:

```
Allocated: 18
Allocated: 10
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f4GhGs64M)</kbd>

---

The most likely reason *why* this happens is that extra bookkeeping of a single `size_t` is being kept at the beginning of allocated arrays containing non-trivial destructors. This would be done so that when `delete` is called, the language can know how many objects require their destructors invoked. For non-trivial destructors, its able to rely on the underlying `delete` mechanics of their deallocation functions.

This hypothesis is also supported by the fact that for the GNU ABI, the extra storage is `sizeof(size_t)` bytes. Building for `x86_64` yields `18` for an allocation of `A[10]` (`8` bytes for `size_t`). [Building for `x86` yields `14`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5j538x9xf) for that same allocation (`4` bytes for `size_t`).

---

#### Edit

I don't recommend doing this in practice, but you can actually *view* this extra data from arrays. The allocated pointer from `new[]` gets adjusted before being returned to the caller ([which you can test by printing the address from the `new[]` operator](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MdoYK7xW1)).

If you read this data into a `std::size_t`, you can see that this data -- at least for the GNU ABI -- contains the exact count for the number of objects allocated.

*Again, I do not recommend doing this in practice since this exploits implementation-defined behavior*. But just for fun:

```cpp
    auto* a = new A[10];
    const auto* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(a);
    std::size_t count;
    std::memcpy(&count, bytes - sizeof(std::size_t), sizeof(std::size_t));

    std::cout << "Count " << count << std::endl;

    delete[] a;
```

The output:

```
Count 10
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8YEvMxa9s)</kbd>

Comment: Holy scheiße my tests are positive for non-trivial destructors extra bookkeeping. Thanks for indulging me.

Comment: @hisdudeness Glad you appreciate the answer! If you're interested, this is exploiting the implementation, but you can actually _view_ the extra bookkeeping. See my edit!

Comment: Oh nice! Memory allocation is weirder than I thought.