# How to call derived class function from base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm a newbie at C++ and I was programming this code below.

This is **DOCUMENT.h**:  It works well and therefore I didn't post its implementation (document.cpp):

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class Document {
private: 
    int id;
    char *titre;

public:
    Document();
    Document(int id, char *titre);
    ~Document();
    Document(const Document &doc);
    Document operator+( Document doc);
    Document operator=(const Document &doc);
    void setId(int id);
    int getId();

    void setTitre(char *titre);
    char *getTitre();
};

class Livre :public Document {
private:
    float price;

public:
    Livre();
    Livre(int id , char *titre,float price);
    ~Livre();
    Livre( Livre &doc);
    Livre operator+(Livre doc);
    Livre operator=( Livre &doc);

    void setPrice(float price);
    virtual float getPrice();
};

class Article :public Document {
private:
    char *date;

public:
    Article();
    Article(int id, char *titre , char *date);
    ~Article();
    Article(Article &doc);
    Article  operator+( Article &doc);
    Article operator=( Article &doc);
    void setDate(char* date);
    char *getDate();
};
```

**MANAGER.H**:

```
#include "Document.h"

class Manager {
private:
    Document **doc ;

public:
    int count = 0;

    Manager();
    ~Manager();

    int  ajouter(Document *d);
    void afficher();

};
```

**MANAGER.CPP**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Manager.h"

Manager::Manager() {}
Manager::~Manager() {}

int  Manager::ajouter(Document *d) {
    if (count == 0) {
        doc = (Document**)malloc( sizeof(Document));
        doc[count] = new Document();

        doc[0] = d;
    }
    else {
        doc = (Document**)realloc(doc, count * sizeof(Document));
        doc[count] = new Document();
        doc[count] = d;
    }
    count++;

    return 0;
}

void Manager::afficher() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\nid : %d  \n", doc[i]->getId());
        printf("titre : %s  \n", doc[i]->getTitre());
        printf("Price : %f  \n", doc[i]->getPrice());
    }

}
```

My problem is in `afficher()` function. I  want to call `getprice()` from there but, `getprice()` is not a member of class `Document` : it's member of `Livre` class (which is a child of `Document`). Is there any way to call `getprice()` ?

Comment: `malloc` and `realloc` are being used incorrectly.  Document should have a `virtual float getPrice();` (which probably ought to be `const`) if you want to use it in the way you describe.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior because of your use of `malloc` and `realloc`. The valid uses for both are so rare in C++ that I would recommend you forget that they exist. The likelihood that you are going to use them correctly as a beginner is very small. Always use `new[]` instead or rather, don't use dynamic allocation at all and use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead (and `std::unique_ptr` for single object allocations). You should almost never have to use `new`/`delete` either.

Comment: Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MgfRRy) answer you question? I can make it into full answer if you want with more explanation.

Comment: If you want to call a member function of `Livre`, you need to create objects of type `Livre`, not its base class `Document`. Do you expect `Manager` to hold pointers to both `Document` and `Livre` instances or only the latter? If the former, what you want to happen if `doc[i]` *doens't* point to an object of type `Livre`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution of your problem

Ideally, `Manager::afficher()` should not have to know the details of `Document`. If should delagate this to a new function `Document::afficher()` and let each type of document decide on what information is to be printed and what is available.  That's the principle of polymorphism:

```
void Manager::afficher() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        doc[i]->afficher();
    }
}
```

If you want nevertheless to infringe the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter),  you can keep your approach.  But you can only use the elements that are available for all the documents.  Unless you know for sure it's a Livre.  In this case you could use dynamic casting:

```
void Manager::afficher() {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\nid : %d  \n", doc[i]->getId());
        printf("titre : %s  \n", doc[i]->getTitre());
        Livre *l = dynamic_cast<Livre*>(doc[i]);  // attempt to see it's a Livre
        if (l) {                     // If it's a Livre l is not null 
            printf("Price : %f  \n", doc[i]->getPrice());
        }
        else printf ("Price : unknown\n"); 
    }
}
```

### Not related, but your code has a lot of issues you are not yet aware of

First of all C++ is not C so `malloc()` should not be used unless you're sure of what you do (i.e. if you know the rules when to use a [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8959635/3723423) or not ).

Furthermore your management of pointers of pointers in `Manager` will lead you directly to a catastrophe:  you allocate a single `Document`, You could eventually handle this as an array of a single document, but with casting wizardry, you make it a pointer to pointer. Ouch !

You need to change the way you manage your collection of documents:

```
   doc = (Document**)malloc( sizeof(Document));   //!!!!! NOOO
```

Since you want to use polymorphism having different kind of specialized documents, you could make your class look like:

```
class Manager {
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Document>> doc ;  // safer way

public:
    Manager();
    ~Manager();
    int  ajouter(shared_ptr<Document> d);
    void afficher();
};
```

`shared_ptr<>` are used like pointers,  but manage the memory by themselves.  `vector` is auto-adatptative:  you just need to `push_back()` an element and it will resize itself if needed.  After, you can index the elements as if with  array.  In addition in counts for you with `vector::size()`;

```
int  Manager::ajouter(shared_ptr<Document> d) {
    doc.push_back(d); 
}
int Manager::compter() {       // you need to add this in your class definition
    return doc.size();         // always up-to date count ! 
}
```

How to add new documents to your library ?

```
auto d1 = make_shared<Document>(); 
... 
manager.ajouter(d1); 
auto d2 = male_shared<Livre>(); 
...
manager.ajouter(d2);
```

For this to work smoothly,  you should also replace your `char*`  with `string` to avoid memory management issues and get the power of C++ strings.

The dynamic casting that I mentioned in my solution works slightly differntly with shared pointers: you have to use [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) instead of `dynamic_cast`.

A last remark.  Whenever you have a single virtual function in a class, you should make the destructor virtual as well.