# Use the specified memory to construct an object and use free(mem) to release it, resulting in memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

There is a code snippet that constructs an object using a specified memory, as shown in the diagram. When I release the specified memory using free(mem), I noticed that the destructor of the Node class is not called. Does this mean that the memory space for the string type key in Node is not released? I suspect there might be a memory leak, but when I ran the test loop, I didn't see the memory constantly increasing. On the contrary, when I wrote my own MyString class, which includes char* data and int length, and replaced std::string with it, I found that the memory kept increasing during the test loop, seemingly leaking. Why is that? Does std::string have any unique characteristics?

```
// using K = std::string;

struct Node {
    K key;
    Node(){}
    Node(const K& k): key(k) {}

    ~Node() {
      printf(" ~node\n");
    }

    void cleal_Key() {
        // key.~K();
        // printf("  clear node\n");
    }
};

void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i< 100000; i++) {
        char* mem = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Node* node = new (mem) Node();
        node->key = "abcdfefdf" + std::to_string(i);
        free(mem); 
    }
}
```

I tested both std::string and MyString, and I find it very surprising that there is no memory leak with std::string.

Comment: You are probably seeing the *small string optimization*, which avoids allocating memory for strings if they are small strings.

Comment: Related: [malloc & placement new vs. new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8959635/11082165)

Comment: `free` doesn't call the destructor, you need to call the destructor manually `mem->~Node();` before calling free.

Comment: Thank you for answering my doubts. Also, you are right, manually calling the destructor can solve the memory leak problem, thank you!